# Importing PNotify with Webpack2

Tags: angular, browser, webpack-2, pnotify

I am trying to use PNotify in my Angular4+Bootstrap3 application.
I have installed the `pnotify npm package` and the `@types/jquery.pnotify` definitions. I have included `import 'pnotify';` in my `vendor.ts`. So far so good, the application compiles without problem.

But I am geting **`PNotify is not defined`** exception in Chrome when the code reaches that point.

My `vendor.js` contains the minified file from dist subfolder as it should.
[image: pnotify in vendor.js]

I have even tried this, without success: https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/212#issuecomment-246915323

What am I missing?